# Not able to traverse through my JSON through Python?

Tags: python

So I have JSON file that contains 4 coordinates of a square. The JSON tree starts off with the index of the squares ID (1, 2, 3... etc) and within each ID we have 4 sets of coordinates (x1,y1 etc). My end goal is to be able to build up an array of coordinates, however, I am unable to access the keys that have the coordinates labeled (x1,y1) and I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated

**main.py**

```
with open('data.json','r') as json_file:
    coordinates = json.load(json_file)

    # We get the length of the number of objects within the json representation
    temp_length = len(coordinates)
    # For each square, access the coordinates
    for x in range (0, temp_length):
        for y in coordinates[x][0]['x1,y1']:
            print(y)
```

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "1": [
      {
        "x1,y1": [
          [
            598,
            326
          ]
        ],
        "x2, y2": [
          [
            598,
            370
          ]
        ],
        "x3, y3": [
          [
            793,
            367
          ]
        ],
        "x4, y4": [
          [
            793,
            303
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "2": [
      {
        "x1,y1": [
          [
            1005,
            170
          ]
        ],
        "x2, y2": [
          [
            1005,
            308
          ]
        ],
        "x3, y3": [
          [
            1130,
            293
          ]
        ],
        "x4, y4": [
          [
            1129,
            169
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Producing this error when running the above :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/main.py", line 20, in main
    for y in coordinates[x][0]['x1,y1']:
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: You don't have a list. You have a dictionary with *string* keys, each containing digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

saved_coordinates = []

with open('data.json','r') as json_file:
    coordinates = json.load(json_file)

    for obj in coordinates:
        for key in obj.keys():
            for cords_list in obj[key]:
                for index, cords in cords_list.items():
                    saved_coordinates.append(cords)
                    print('index: ' + index + '\ncoordinates: ' + str(cords) + '\n')

print(saved_coordinates)
```

**Output:**

```
index: x4, y4
coordinates: [[793, 303]]

index: x3, y3
coordinates: [[793, 367]]

index: x2, y2
coordinates: [[598, 370]]

index: x1,y1
coordinates: [[598, 326]]

index: x4, y4
coordinates: [[1129, 169]]

index: x3, y3
coordinates: [[1130, 293]]

index: x2, y2
coordinates: [[1005, 308]]

index: x1,y1
coordinates: [[1005, 170]]

[[[793, 303]], [[793, 367]], [[598, 370]], [[598, 326]], [[1129, 169]], [[1130, 293]], [[1005, 308]], [[1005, 170]]]
```

Comment: Glad to have been for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing integers to a dictionary that only has string keys. `0` is not the same thing as `"0"`, and your sample data doesn't even have a `"0"` key (only `"1"` and `"2"` are present).

Don't generate integers. Just loop over the values or items of the dictionary:

```
for square_id, nested_list in coordinates.items():
    for coord in nested_list[0]['x1,y1']:
        print("ID:", square_id)
        print("Coordinate:", coord)
```

If you don't need access to the key (assigned to `square_id` in the above loop), then just use `for nested_list in coordinates.values():`.